# Creating Object Properties in JSON (Javascript) Dynamically in a Method

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, properties

I am left scratching my head here. I am pretty new with both JSON and Javascript so I am wondering how I would go about this.

Say I have an object:

```
MyObject.prototype = {
    // different methods and properties
    _randomMethod: function MyObject_randomMethod() {
         MyObject.myArray = [];
    },
};
```

How do I declare an array property for my object (like above: `MyObject.myArray = [];`) and have it available throughout the object so I can access it in other methods.

Maybe this has already been covered and I am just not using the right terminology but if someone could help me out, I'd appreciate it since I can't figure it out myself.

Just so its clear, I want to declare this array property dynamically within a method like the example above and then be able to use it in other methods within this same object with the '`this`' reference or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this` to refer to the current instance:

```
MyObject.prototype = {
    // different methods and properties
    _randomMethod: function MyObject_randomMethod() {
         this.myArray = [];
    },
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5jSe3/